# Do I need a smartphone with more RAM or one with a higher processor in order to load a big excel file faster?

Tags: hardware, ram, processor, microsoft-excel

As the title says, do I need a smartphone with more RAM or one with a higher processor in order to load a big excel file faster ?

For instance : Snapdragon 835 with 8GB RAM vs Snapdragon 845 with 6GB RAM, which is faster to load a big excel file ?

Answer (score 1):

RAM should not be an issue with smartphones that have 6GB or 8GB of it (I have 1GB 
 and Excel workbooks load fine - not really large ones) . So, in that case, it would be the processor. Also, a factor not mentioned in your question: the RAM speed. A lot of smartphones have RAM at 1033Mhz or 1.6Ghz, making a really fast processor pointless without RAM that can support those speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Normally 3GB or 4GB Ram coupled with the 1.5 GHz processor is enough to open a medium size excel document file. If you use a 8GB ram smartphone device with snapdragon 845 CPU So there is a slight difference in opening Excel file.